# Flask- How to fix img '404 picture not found' in html

Tags: html, image, filepath

I set up a server, am trying to load a picture on the web page, I get the alt tag to show up but the picture will not load. I have the picture in file structure '/templates/images/pic' . I have the src tag defined as '/images/pic' but it will still not load Is this an environment problem?

I have tried moving the picture into the folder with the html files and changing the src tag but still nothing

html

```
        <img src="/mymodules/images/computer"
     alt="HTML5 Icon"
     name="pic"
      style="width:128px;height:128px;">
```

python code for homepage

```
@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def home() -> 'html':
return render_template('entry.html', page_title='Logica1 Err0r')
```

I have got the 404 error every time

Comment: src should include the full path to the image file, including the filename. `src="/path/to/image.jpg"`

Answer (score 1):

I think I see your problem.
You need the WHOLE path of the image.
if you say the name of the image is pic, then your code should be

```
<img src="/mymodules/images/computer/templates/images/pic.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;>
```

Hope this helps! If it is still not working, I'll reformat my answer because the way you have your image path isn't that clear to me, but I'll figure it out.

Comment: I did add the whole file path still did not work, this has been happening with multiple elements I'm trying to call, is it possible that there is something wrong with my environment? I have all my HTML files in a 'templates' folder inside my 'webapp' folder that has my main python app that runs the server.

Comment: Ok, can you go to a website like https://codepen.io and put your code there so I can see your problem?